# How can I override Django filter

Tags: python, django

I want to override `timesince` Django's template filter for creating a more efficient filter for getting relative times.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create your own filter to do what you want: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

Monkeypatch `django.utils.timesince.timesince` with your desired function.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I ask for a way which doesn't force me to change Django files. The reason is obvious, probably I want this changes only for an application or a project.

Comment: Read the first sentence proper of the article. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch

Comment: Ok, I getted. Now the question is: how can I monkeypatch that files?

Comment: `import django.utils.timesince` `django.utils.timesince.timesince = mytimesince`